# Dataframe operations involving nan

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to subtract row with nan values from all rows in a Dataframe. For this I am using

```
dataframe.sub(row, axis= 1)
```

this ignores nan values, i.e. if either of the values in two rows is nan, the result is nan. I want that if either of the values is not nan, the subtraction  should proceed taking the nan value to be 0. If both are not nan, the result should be the difference.If both are nan, the result should be nan. For example, subtraction of the following two rows should be as below,

```
[1, 2, nan, nan, 5] - [nan, 5, 1, nan, 2] = [1 , -3, -1, nan, 3]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @JoeR yes , thank you

Comment: Can you just use `DataFrame.fillna(0)`?

Comment: [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) (docs linked) will return a copy of the dataframe with NaNs filled to the specified value.  You might look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want that if either of the values is not nan, the subtraction should proceed taking the nan value to be 0. If both are not nan, the result should be the difference.

Use `fillna` to set `nan`-values to 0, then apply a mask to reset the result to `nan` where both input values were `nan`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# sample data
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1, 2, nan, nan, 5],
                    'b': [nan, 5, 1, nan, 2] })
# get all rows with both values nan
nan_mask = df.a.isnull() & df.b.isnull()
# calculate with all nans set to 0
result = df.a.fillna(0) - df.b.fillna(0)
# set rows with both nans to nan
result[nan_mask] = nan
print list(result)
=> [1.0, -3.0, -1.0, nan, 3.0]
```

**Update**

If you are looking for a more concise solution it turns out that `df.sub(other, fill_value=0.0)` achieves the same thing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1, 2, nan, nan, 5],
                    'b': [nan, 5, 1, nan, 2]})
result = df.a.sub(df.b, fill_value=0.0)
=> [1.0, -3.0, -1.0, nan, 3.0]
```

[From the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

> fill_value : None or float value, default None (NaN)
>       Fill missing (NaN) values with this value. If both Series are
>       missing, the result will be missing

Comment: downvote all you like but please add a comment so I can improve the answer.